# swing JTable with ScrollBar - color of square between headers and track

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollbar

[image]

I have a JTable with BasicScrollBarUI, I set the headers background color: table.getTableHeader().setBackground(GuiConstants.backgroundColor);

and the scrolbar background color:
public class ScrollBarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {

```
@Override
protected void paintTrack(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle trackBounds) {
    c.setBackground(GuiConstants.backgroundColor);

}
```

}

I still have a square between them that its color won't change.
does anybody knows how to change it also to their color?

thanks

Comment: You could also just implement a custom `Look and Feel` for it. Haven't come across that issue before

Comment: It's called a corner...take a look at [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)

Comment: setCorner() helped, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in [*How to Use Scroll Panes: Providing Custom Decorations*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations), you can use the scroll pane's `setCorner()` method to add a colored `Component`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, panel);
```

You may have to set the panel's [opacity](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#props) to `true`, and you may want to select a suitable color from the the current Look & Feel using the [`UIManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/UIManager.html).