# Background of background JTable header color

Tags: java, swing

You can see on the following picture a part of my application. Basically a `JFrame` containing, between other things : a `JTable` within a `JScrollPane`.

I set the background color on both elements (see A) but where can I set the color on the arrow B ?

[image: Problem illustration]

Declared as follow :

public class CXPanel extends JPanel{
    private JTablet_ao = new JTable(ViewsModelService.getCXTableModel(0));

```
public CXPanel() {
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    (...)
    this.add(new CXSubPanel(), c);
}


public class CXSubPanel extends GamePanel {
    public CXSubPanel() {
        super(new GridLayout(3, 0, 0, 0));

        TableScrollPane sc_ao = new TableScrollPane();

        (... adding JTable to scrollpane ect...)

        this.add(sc_ao);
    }
}
```

}

The back ground color is set for each panel, `scrollpane` (and its `viewport`) cell and header renderer of the table, example of header renderer :

```
public class CXHeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

        public CXHeaderRenderer() {
            this.setFont(ViewsPreferences.CX_HEADER_FONT);
            this.setForeground(ViewsPreferences.CX_HEADER_COLOR);
            this.setBackground(ViewsPreferences.CX_HEADER_BACKGROUND);
            this.setOpaque(true);
            this.setBorder(null);
            this.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ViewsPreferences.P_HEADER_WIDTH, ViewsPreferences.P_HEADER_HEIGHT));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText(value.toString());
            return this;
        }

    }
```

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Done, but I really doubt that helps that's why I didn't sent you all. I didn't wanted to have a post with useless code when "the background color in the scrollpane/panel/jtable/tableheader is set" can resume it in one sentence.

Comment: Not done -- please read or re-read the [mcve] link again. You're right, we don't want the full code, but most here find it *much* easier to understand a problem **quickly** if we can run ready made small code that shows it to us. If you don't get an answer soon, then I would suggest that you consider writing a new program from scratch, one that exposes your problem in all its nakedness as this is a useful tool to use, not only for asking questions here, but also for solving the issue yourself. When I've been in in your shoes, I've used this tool and have found it **extremely** useful.

Comment: Find here a post similar to mine with minimal code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708734/swing-jtable-with-scrollbar-color-of-square-between-headers-and-track

I tried this technique but does not solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

Aswer found (partially on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708734/swing-jtable-with-scrollbar-color-of-square-between-headers-and-track)) :

```
table.getTableHeader().setBackground(myColor);
scrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, dummyPanel);
```

Learn more about `JScrollPane` corners [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations), good thing to know : each `JTable`contains a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: No, each table does not contain a `JScrollPane`, a `JTable` is wrapped into a `JScrollPane` and can configure itself when done so